# AppTrackingTransparency permission is mandatory for FBSDK Login?

Tags: swift, single-sign-on, ios14, facebook-sdk-4.0, apptrackingtransparency

I am using FBSDK for single sign-on do we need to add the app AppTrackingTransparency permission in the IOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it... it is pretty clear on the [Facebook Getting Started site in the Get Consent section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios/)

**> Get Device Consent**

> Starting with iOS 14.5, you will need to set AdvertiserTrackingEnabled
> and log each time you give a device permission to share data with
> Facebook. If a device provides consent, call the
> setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled method of the FBSDKSettings class and set
> it to YES for Objective-C or true for Swift. If a device does not
> allow tracking, set setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled to NO for Objective-C
> or false for Swift. The method will return a boolean value to indicate
> whether the method is set successfully or not.

Comment: We are not using any advertisement Framework. we are just using Facebook single sign-on. So AppTrackingTransparency Not Require right?

Comment: Probably because of how Facebook collects everything. The framework probably uses it even though you/your app don’t need it. You have to look at the Facebook privacy policy and include what they take in yours. You are responsible for everything 3rd party frameworks do in your app. They are being clear they want you to tell them if you have permission.